# Getting errors using Auth and firestore dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I started a new Flutter project and when I use either or both dependencies in pubspec.yaml for Auth and Firestore, I get all sorts of errors. These are from the Flutter Packages website:

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

firebase_auth: ^0.8.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0

My second question is, if the project needs both Auth and Firestore, how can I reference both dependencies?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was working on my newest project as well, and I ended up using a older version like this:

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3
```

Hopefully they resolve the conflict soon and we can just use the newest version.

Comment: Yes, when I use the older ones it works partially, because sometimes I can not mic Auth and Firestore plugins in the same project. I get lots of dependency errors as well.

Comment: For me, there was no need to use older versions. I just opened the android folder of the app in android studio and clicked Refactor -> migrate to androidX and then Do refactor. And it worked